# Is $k[x, x^{-1}]$ a (graded) injective $k[x]$-module

Tags: polynomials, duality-theorems, graded-rings, injective-module, graded-modules

Consider $k[x]$ with the usual grading, and the graded $k[x]$-module $k[x, x^{-1}]$. Is it injective? I suppose yes, because it is torsion free and graded divisible (i.e., divisible by homogeneous elements), and I am just assuming that a torsion free graded module is injective if and only if it is graded divisible, generalizing from [the respective statement about ungraded modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2075757/a-torsion-free-divisible-module-over-a-commutative-integral-domain-is-injective?rq=1). On the otherhand, the duality $(-)^*$ of $k[x]$-modules with $M^* = \hom_k(M, k)$ is contravariant exact, and thus sends injective modules to projective ones. But $(k[x,x^{-1}])^* = k[x, x^{-1}]$ is [not projective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377452/non-finitely-generated-non-divisible-non-projective-flat-module-over-a-polyn) as ungraded module, and thus also not [projective as graded module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756555/projective-graded-modules), so $k[x, x^{-1}]$ is not injective.

What am I doing wrong here?